# Limiting memory on dotnet command

Tags: c#, .net

I have a web application created with **Angular**, with **.Net** back-end. The app is started with `npm run start`". the command behind this is:

> node --max_old_space_size=2048 svg-sprite && rimraf ./dev/dist && dotnet run

As you can see above I know how to limit the memory used by NodeJs, but my app still fails on my lowly MacBook with 8gb of ram. It fails when it tries to run the:

> dotnet run

I thought about wrapping it in a Docker container and limiting the memory of that, but that doesn't have expected behavior. Is there a way to accomplish what I need without modifying the core codebase? (I can't do that it's not my code).

Edit:

Here are the current failure messages:
- `System.TimeoutException`
or
- `JavaScript heap out of memory`

My guess is the .Net tries to run Angular and it fails somewhere in there.

Comment: _but my app still fails_ - fails how? What's the error? OutOfMemory or something else?

Comment: There is a [`COMPLUS_GCHeapHardLimit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/run-time-config/garbage-collector#systemgcheaphardlimitcomplus_gcheaphardlimit) environment variable that can be used for this purpose (disclaimer: not tested).

Comment: Note that `dotnet` does attempt to respect the memory limits of a Docker container as well as it can, so if that doesn't have the desired effect there's no good reason to assume limiting it outside the container would have better results. If it needs more memory than there is, it's not going to work in any case.

Comment: "JavaScript heap out of memory" sound to me like you didn't give node enough memory.  Not .net.